# Entity Framework + SQL Server CE 4.0 in a .DLL loaded in AutoCAD 2012x64

Tags: sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4.3, autocad

I have a tough problem. I want to make a .dll that is "netload"-ed inside AutoCAD 2012 and I want to use EF + SQL Server CE 4.0 Private Installation in order to be able to XCopy the program.

I don't want to install SQL Server CE 4.0 on the client machine so I have chosen the Private Installation. The problem is that it relies on config file which is not an option here because I want XCopy the program only!

I am using the nuget package `EntityFramework.SqlCompact`. Whatever I try I get an

> unable to find the requested .net framework data provider

exception inside AutoCAD, because AutoCAD has its own config which is almost empty.

Is there any way to configure the app to use the locally copied dll-s without config at all? Is there a way to include another config?

I can post example code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by Entity Framework, not SQL Compact, as EF relies on the DbProvider configuration. So if you use classic ADO.NET instead for data access, private deployment will work, otherwise you must have this in your app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.data>
 <DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
 </DbProviderFactories>
 </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But the problem is that I am loading my program as a dll inside AutoCAD and not exe and I don`t have the config. Is there a way to use a config with dll? I tried to insert this config in acad.exe.config but still the same.
I have posted example code here : http://www.mediafire.com/file/yucyc9pot1kj1rp/CAD_SqlCe_Ef.zip/file/yucyc9pot1kj1rp/CAD_SqlCe_Ef.zip

Comment: The correct verion here - http://www.mediafire.com/?cd8f1chbief99g2 The problem is that I cannot use config or just don`t know how to use it with dll.

Comment: There are a lot of examples showing how to do it while the SqlCe is in GAC already or with config. Even the examples that are labeled as "private install" on MS docs are not private, because they rely ot SqlCe in GAC. I need it without GAC. If there is a way to make the config work while the program is in dll - it will be fine for me. I have posted here after reading whatever I have found and tried. Thank you for your time! I really appreciate that!

Comment: As I already said, there is no way you can do this, if EF is required. See my blog post here on Private Deployment - for ADO.NET, no config required. -http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you for your answer. I follow your posts but it seems that I missed that obvious one. Thanks once again.

Comment: Is it possible to create the connection to SqlCe in code and provide it to the EF? In other words to make my own connection provider for that particular case?

Comment: I do not think  that is possible, no